# Facing issue with my bootstrap contact form

Tags: php

I updated my PHP to 7.3 and my contact form stopped working. I keep getting an error saying: "Please correct the following error:Your Name Hit the back button and try again.:

No matter what I do, I cannot get it load, even if i remove the input functions it send the email, but with no content.

Any help would be great, thank you.

Code Below:

```
HTML
   <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-9">
            <h5>Contact us to get a free quote</h5>
                <form name="contactform" method="post" action="../mailer.php" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputName" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Name</label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" name="inputName" placeholder="Your Name">
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="inputPhone" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Phone</label>
                  <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPhone" name="inputPhone" placeholder="Your Phone Number">
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputEmail" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email</label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" name="inputEmail" placeholder="Your Email">
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputMessage" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Message</label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                  <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" id="inputMessage" name="inputMessage" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                    Send Message
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
            </div> <!-- End of sm 9 form --> 

PHP

<?php
/* Set e-mail recipient */
//$myemail = "dummy@dummy.com,"+ $email;

$arrEmail = array('dummy@dummy.com', $email);

/* Check all form inputs using check_input function */
$name = check_input($_POST['inputName'], "Your Name");
$phone = check_input($_POST['inputPhone'], "Your Phone Number");
$email = check_input($_POST['inputEmail'], "Your E-mail Address");
$message = check_input($_POST['inputMessage'], "Your Message");

/* If e-mail is not valid show error message */
if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
{
show_error("Invalid e-mail address");
}
/* Let's prepare the message for the e-mail */

$subject = "New Message";

$message = "  

Name: $name
Phone: $phone
Email: $email
---
Message:
$message
---
"

/* Send the message using mail() function */
foreach($arrEmail as $key => $email_to){
mail($email_to, $subject, $message);
}

/* Redirect visitor to the thank you page */
header('Location: contact.php?email=sent');
exit();

/* Functions we used */
function check_input($data, $problem='')
{
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
{
show_error($problem);
}
return $data;
}

function show_error($myError)
{
?>
<html>

<body>

<p>Please correct the following error:</p>
<strong><?php echo $myError; ?></strong>
<p>Hit the back button and try again</p>


</body>
</html>
<?php
exit();``
}
?>
```

Comment: It seems `strlen($data) == 0` is true for the inputName input.

Comment: @biztrick I'm not able to reproduce the issue. See https://repl.it/@jasny/stackoverflow-59759731